# Переменная в форматировании пробелами. A constant value is expected c#

Tags: c#, строки, форматирование

Я могу форматировать пробелами, используя литерал:

```cs
string text = "text";
Console.WriteLine($"{text, -10}|");
```

Но если передам вместо литерала переменную, то появится ошибка **CS0150: A constant value is expected**:

```
int border = 10;
Console.WriteLine($"{text, -border}|");
```

Или

```cs
int border = -10;
Console.WriteLine($"{text, border}|");
```

*Как можно сделать форматирование пробелами, если заранее неизвестно какое число понадобится передать в форматирование*? Я бы мог просто дать нужное значение переменной, но видимо форматирование не работает с переменными.

Comment: Число в форматировании означает не количество пробелов, а длину результата, пробелы сами подберутся для нужной длины строки

Comment: Согласен, ну а что делать, если заранее неизвестно какое число нужно подать на форматирование?

Comment: Тут нужно либо `PadLeft`, `PadRight` использовать, либо делать форматирование в два этапа: сперва саму строку формата составлять динамически, потом её применять.

Comment: const int border = 10; ?

Comment: @LiptonDev тоже вариант, работает.